# JRuby debugger doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby, debugging, jruby

today I gave JRuby a try to use it with Apache's Mahout. But I have a problem with the debugger. When I put the `debugger` statement on a specific place, it doesn't stop there. It stops later at the end of the script, and then of course none of the variables are available. This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

platform :jruby do
  gem "jruby_mahout"
  gem "ruby-debug"
end
```

This is the Script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-debug'

puts "I am called"
debugger
puts "I should not be called before the debugger"
```

But the output is:

```
I am called
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@mahout/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4-java/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:215 warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag
I should not be called
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@mahout/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:129
finalize if respond_to?(:finalize)
(rdb:1)
```

I'm wondering why there is this warning `tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag`, because I started the script with `jruby test.rb --debug`

I installed JRuby 1.7.3 with RVM on my OS X 10.8, and when calling `jruby -version` I get this output:

```
jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) 2013-02-21 dac429b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_43-b01-447-11M4203 [darwin-x86_64]
NameError: undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object
  (root) at -e:1
```

Maybe the installation is broken, or I'm doing sth wrong. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it on my own. After a long time of trying, I accidentially putted the `--debug` statement between:

```
jruby --debug test.rb
```

It's weird, but now it works as expected.